# Can not save data from mongoose query

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

When im logging data from db like this:

```
router.get("/names", async (req, res) => {
    ListItemsModel.find({}, function (err, items) {
        items.forEach(item => {
            console.log(item.name);
        });
    });
});
```

but of om trying to save it into array, it returns me an empty object:

```
router.get("/names", async (req, res) => {
    let listNames = new Array();

    ListItemsModel.find({}, function (err, items) {
        items.forEach(item => {
            listNames.push(item.name);
        });
    });
    console.log(listNames);
});
```

Can someone suggest a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ListItemsModel.find` is an asyncronous call and thus executes **after** `console.log(listNames);`. That's why you don't see anything in that array.

There are 2 ways to fix this.

1. Since you are using an `async` function to handle the route `async (req, res) => {...`, You can easily change your code to `await` for the `find` command. Like this:

```
router.get("/names", async (req, res) => {
    const lists = await ListItemsModel.find();
    const listNames = lists.map(x => x.name)
    console.log(listNames);
});
```

2. This one is just super obvious. Simply move the `console.log(listNames)` into the callback function and you will get your result.

```
router.get("/names", async (req, res) => {
    let listNames = new Array();

    ListItemsModel.find({}, function (err, items) {
        items.forEach(item => {
            listNames.push(item.name);
        });
        console.log(listNames);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a callback function like this:
Have your route callback function

```
router.get("/names", async (req, res) => {
    let listNames= [];

    getListItems((err,items){

         if(err) console.log(err)
         listNames = items.map((element){ 
               return element.name;
         })
    })
});
```

Have a controller to run your model logic

```
getListItems(callback){
    ListItemsModel.find({}, function (err, items) {
        if(err){ callback(err,null)}
        else{
           callback(null,items);
        }
    });
}
```